# Why am I getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException with an iterator?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, iterator

I'm trying to write a game, so every frame I call the doDraw() method where I'm using an iterator to loop through all GameObjects and print them all on screen:

```
Iterator<GameObject> itr = mObjList.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        GameObject obj = itr.next(); // this line gives me the error
        ...
        // print object
    }
```

The only method that adds item to the list, is this:

```
public void click(int x, int y) {
    // adds new object to the list on a click event
    mObjList.add(new GameObject(x, y));
}
```

Most of the times it works. But sometimes I get this error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

From the line with "itr.next()". From what I've googled, I figured this is because the click() event sometimes happen before the draw() finishes drawing every object, so it's changing the list while the iterator is using it. I suppose this is what's wrong?

But I'm not experienced with threads. How could I possibly fix this? Maybe I'm doing this whole thing wrong and I should use a completely different method to print all objects on screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the expected number of reads and traversals greatly outnumbers the number of updates to the list, use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Otherwise, `synchronize` on the list (or a dedicated mutex object) when iterating and mutating:

```
private List<GameObject> mObjList = /* whatever */;
private final Object mListMutex = new Object();

// snip...

synchronized (mListMutex) {
    for (GameObject obj : mObjList) {
        // do your thang
    }
}

// snip...
public void click(int x, int y) {
    GameObject obj = new GameObject(x, y);
    synchronized (mListMutex) {
        mObjList.add(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like add to the answer from @aleph_null.  @aleph_null is correct that this exception happens when you try to modify a collection while you are iterating across it -- only the `remove()` method on the iterator is allowed.  The iterator is trying to protect itself from changes happening to the collection underneath it.

I would not, however, recommend synchronization as the right solution.  If you need the behavior of adding stuff to a list while you are processing it then I recommend adding to another list and then calling `addAll()` once you stop iterating.   More GC intensive for sure but cleaner.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I missed the fact that the `click()` is an asynchronous event handed by another thread.  I assumed that the `click()` was called inside the loop.  You will have to synchronize around the list when you add in `click()` and around the `addAll()`.  You could use an `AtomicReference` to record the click and then act on it after the iterator finished but only if you were guaranteed of only one item being clicked on at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion still leaves a synchronization problem. the click method would be adding an element to a temporary list in the UI thread and the same list would be used in the addAll method on a different thread. You would be moving the sync problems from one list to another.

Comment: Yes, but it's less of a problem.  Queueing up the items requires a lock on a thread-safe queue add - quick.  Sychronizing on the list means the adding thread has to block until the draw iteration is complete - a lengthy operation. The drawing thread can empty the queue after each frame-draw iteration is complete, as suggested by @Gray.

Comment: ..or empty the queue before the iteration starts, or it may be possible to queue up the updates to whatever the draw thread waits on when it is not drawing, (eg. if it's a UI thread, post it a Windows message/BeginInvoke/whateverItIsInJavaIcantRemember).  Whatever  - the list only gets updated from the drawing thread so no lengthy locking.  Basically, the longer a lock is taken, the poorer the performance and the greater the chance of deadlocks.

Comment: In fact, +1 for daring to suggest that synchronization over a lengthy operation might be a bad idea.

Comment: I missed the fact that `click()` was an event handled in another thread.  I've edited my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gray - you were close enough. Most developers, including myself, just assumed you meant a thread-safe queue/list.  It's still much better than locking over the iteration of a lengthy listful of complex drawing methods.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not use an iterator, or somehow ping-pong between lists so that the one you're modifying is not the one you're iterating through.  You could also try to use synchronization, but that requires some fairly sophisticated skills to do well without creating deadlocks.

Comment: I don't think we should be making people *afraid* of synchronization when it's clearly what's needed.  If you don't want to deal with synchronization you have no business building a multithreaded application.  And deadlocks are in fact very easy to avoid, especially for trivial synchronization like this (where you're probably not going to need to synchronize on two things at once).

Comment: How can I do this without an iterator? And what exactly do you mean by ping-pong between lists?

Comment: I've read in tutorials that the "synchronize" keyword is very slow and should be avoided unless there's no other way. Since this is a performance critical part of the code (method running many times per second). Shouldn't I be worried?

Comment: "Since this is a performance critical part of the code (method running many times per second). Shouldn't I be worried?" - is this really a part of the code that is critical? did you do any measurement to verify that belief, or was it just a gut feeling? Just do the synchronization, and then when it becomes slow, _then_ go fix it via a non-blocking datastructure.

Comment: @Mark http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004489/why-am-i-getting-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-with-an-iterator/8004554#8004554

Comment: @VIBrunazo synchronize is not _that_ slow. It used to be very slow, now it's not so bad. It will have an impact, but if you need it, then you need it, and usually it's fast enough not to worry about. Like Chii says, try it and then change it if you have real problem

Comment: @VIBrunazo in particular uncontended synchronization is extremely fast these days.

Comment: Umn guys why exactly would we need any synchronization here? We're only adding elements to the end of the array, so why not go with the simple solution? `for (int i = 0, size = mObjList.size(); i < size; i++) {stuff here}` - that's assuming we don't want newly added objects to be drawn in that cycle (even simpler otherwise). If click is only called from the EDT we don't even need some synchronization when adding objects.

Comment: @VIBrunazo: Even if something is slow you need to put it into perspective.  Running "many times per second" wouldn't be an issue even if synchronized was slow unless you defined "many" to be in the order of hundreds of thousands.

Comment: @VIBrunazo -- Just code a standard `for` loop, instead of using an iterator.

Comment: @MarkPeters -- I wouldn't say that synchronization is "clearly" what is needed here.  What's needed is to not modify the object of an iterator, and the simplest way to accomplish that is to not use an iterator.  Yes, synchronization would likely fix this one case, but would not fix the case where he's modifying the object inside the loop, and with synchronization it's easy to fall into the trap of synchronizing everything "just to be safe", or because weird things are happening (as when modification occurs from inside the loop) and suddenly have an unmanageable mess.

Comment: @Daniel: Sorry, my point was less that "synchronization is the answer" and more that "you can't escape learning about synchronization if you're making a multi-threaded application."  Synchronization might not be the best solution here, but it is *a* solution and the OP should understand the synchronization solution to make an informed choice.

Comment: Lots of things the OP should understand that he doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

noooo, synchronization errors are nasty... especially since they seem to occur randomly. While traversing a collection with an iterator, you cannot modify the collection (unless you use the iterator's remove method, but that's an exception). Doing so results in the exception you're looking at... but only sometimes. The error will occur only when mObjList.add gets called right when you're traversing the iterator.

Comment: The right way to fix this issue is through synchronization. It's not that difficult once you understand the concept... I recommend searching for tutorials... in particular, you can use the "synchronized" keyword or a Semaphore. They will make sure they only ONE of the two conflicting code segments runs concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess about why you're getting the `ConcurrentModificationException` is right on.

To fix this, you could synchronize on the list itself:

```
synchronized(mObjList) {
    Iterator itr = mObjList.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This will allow your thread to acquire a lock on the list itself. If you wrap your access to the list from the other thread in a similar fashion, it will prevent your threads from stepping on each other (see [Intrinsic Locks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)).

I can't tell from context if this would wreak unnecessary havoc in your other thread, but if the list is small-ish it shouldn't be problem. It will certainly cause less problems than an intermittent exception.